# Typescript & React: Provide default value for discriminating union

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a component that has two sets of different props, that can be differentiated using "discriminating unions". This I got working. Now my issues is this: most of the time (let's say 90%), I use the `LinkLinkProps`. So I would like for it to default to one of them, without specifying the discriminating value.

Here is a minimal example showing the issue:

```
type LinkLinkProps = Omit<JSX.IntrinsicElements['a'], 'onClick'> & {
    as: 'link'
}

type LinkButtonProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements['button'] & {
    as: 'button'
}

type LinkProps = LinkLinkProps | LinkButtonProps

function Link(props: LinkProps) {
    if (props.as === "button")  return <button>Link</button>
    return <a>Link</a>
}

function Playground() {
    return (
        <>
            /** Correct */
            <Link as="button" onClick={console.log} href="" />
            /** Correct */
            <Link as="link" onClick={console.log} href="" />
            /** ⛔️ Want to type this the same as using as="link" */
            <Link href="asd" onClick={console.log} />
        </>
    )
}
```

[Here is a playground with the following example.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBFApgQwMbwGZQiOByJNGPAKBJgE8xE4AZYAOwGt7mAFbMAZzgF44A8iGAwAPACkAygA0AdAEkGMKIy7BUAUQA2iEIiVcA2nmR4AugBp8EBgGEt6pngB8cAGRwA3iTi+4yLgAufAdmUgBfMkpqOkYmACEAVxgYGw4Ibj44KTlFZVV1bV19GCM8ACNk1IZzdy8fPwDgiqqbCKiqGlYmdMz+bu7engAfWOYklLTOLjIMRIZ0YBsxpgAKMGngwemASnq-OGAMOHXp2QC+Xn4AIkrJhmu9hEQYRKgGOFE76udu0QB6b42ZwNXxIV7vT7IX5xAHQkiREhzBYwJYfNhaZAUADm2HmABNVntvAdwW8PqtQQdPiDqXS4P8AFSMuC2aBIdBwRn-Kn0z7dfxcXi3VoPOA2eyOXieVA2LgQHSyLQQbHhOAACyQGGF1wZtL5fiZLLZUA58G5vPpogFAWFoSYuolDlQTGlsoY8sVytVGq1Or1lrpRrggBWyQDwf3AAOrIJRwVJxzpx9XAHgwdU0LjIPSCuCJNQMbGCu1xXUWg1+a1xX2IbXXAL4x12Z2umVyhWIJUqtX-fV0gG9uA7BFAA)

**So How can I still have the discrimination, but without specifying the `as` prop everytime?**

Comment: Your "correct" examples are incorrect (`button` elements don't have an `href`). Or did you mean it was correct that it was showing an error? Please also when sharing a playground link ensure that the playground has only relevant errors. (Yours has several irrelevant ones you can fix with `import React from "react";`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean it correctly reports errors.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a solution but it has a downside. Let me first show the solution:

```
type PossibleTypes = "link" | "button";

type LinkProps<Type> = (Type extends "button"
  ? JSX.IntrinsicElements["button"]
  : Omit<JSX.IntrinsicElements["a"], "onClick">) & {
  as?: Type extends PossibleTypes ? Type : never;
};

function Link<Type>(props: LinkProps<Type>) {
  if (props.as === "button") return <button>Link</button>;
  return <a>Link</a>;
}
```

so, as you can see, I made it a generic functional component with `Type` which will be inferred using `as` and the condition will handle the button/link part of the type.

---

The downside is that you lose the intellisense on `as` (not sure if there's a way to get it back, I'm barely intermediate in TS). It does however give error if we try to pass

```
<Link ... as="something other than link/button"... />
```

**Edit:** needed to make `as` optional, with that it seems to work

---

[updated playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChSYBPMJOABQgGdHgAjAGyQBVqlG4AvAXbAAdgGt8cAD4FWAVxgwIoshV5wAMmPF0cYRgB4eNAHyC4AChO0kADxhJRAE374FSlWThwA-HAApAGUADQA6AElRGCgxFjQAUU4QJxhGAG13RWVVAF1SHwAuOAB5EGAYQ2DwqJi44ETk1Iz8FHxcgBoCFQBhETRJUwBKOAAyOABvArgURl9imzh7Rxd+BmY2Tht+f0Xi0SQANyQoUgBfckx5UQxgFS0dY15TSzB9RmLtCT0IAyezEZTHzATBWN6-RhhWaCARCLKeVQjIgweRQURwQweHKmL7iQwAeixKlM02RqPRhhQOMe+Kp50u11u9zo7BQlAA5jhrs5LIDSUgUWirNMfIYST4JXB8QAqaVwHrQIgYODS-EiiWGXEzRgCeE5KS9friAQTNAqRgQThhdgQdlnOAACyImF1Unx4slUtl8sVSGVqvVoq1s11IgkBtEfQaxtN5stSGttvtTqQLvwbo9kplcsAK2SAeD+4AB1FDRODKMsaGAO4D8Ku0RgoFLauDyFiidna0M6KQBz0YrUptOzZwRqMDE1m0QWq02u1SzMS7NwfNFkvwctUGhl6u1h31xu0aGtsQdkP4MOSFVqvuanSO5264cZ9UEj1DelAA)

Comment: That's a cool solution. Maybe it is possible to add back the intellisense for the `as` prop. Will take a look. Edit: @T.J.Crowder you are right.

Comment: updated the answer.. hopefully didn't miss any scenarios this time? still no intellisense though

Comment: Very clever approach! ([Full set of tests](https://tsplay.dev/WzOq2w)) As you say, no intellisense on `as`, but I'm struggling to see how you'd get it. @eivindml - You will have already considered this, but for me `<Link` and `<LinkButton` are starting to look quite good... :-)

Comment: We also have a `<Button` that semantically could be a link, so then we would have: `<Link`, `<LinkButton`, `<Button` and `<ButtonLink`. 